# Using checkbox to determine next step in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, checkbox

I am using a checkbox to determine if a new user will be associated to an existing company or if they will need to add a company to be associated with.

This is the checkbox code:

```
Checkbox(
                  value: _chkbxValue,
                  onChanged: (bool? value) {
                    setState(() {
                      ref
                          .read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                          .updateAddCompany(value!);
                    });
                  },
                ),
```

In the onChanged: I set a global notifierprovider to the state of the checkbox which would be "true".

However, when I get down to the navigation code, the notifierprovider is back to "false" but I don't have any code that changes the notifierprovider.

Here is the navigation code. This code only gets executed when the "Save" button is pressed:

```
if (ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).addCompany!) {
                        ref
                            .read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateAddCompany(false);
                        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const CompanyScreen()));
                      } else {
                        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => MainScreen()));
                      }
```

I am thinking I am not understanding the execution flow of the code. This code is all in a ConsumerStatefulWidget class.

When I press the "Save" button some how the value of the notifierprovider gets changed to "false". How can I do this the right way?

Thanks.

Comment: where is _chkbxValue initialized?

Comment: At the top of the class bool _chkbxValue = false;

Comment: Inside build() or as a variable in State?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when u trying to use the ref.read , u dont need to set state , if ur notitfier , u have the state , and just watch it from the widget , and when u change it by using the read , the parts when u using the watch will be rebuilt, and consider using watch when u checking for a value instead of a read ,